# Progress bar in VB 6.0 from Transcoding process in FFMPEG

Tags: vb6, ffmpeg, progress-bar, transcoding

firts excuse me for my English it`s super Freak. Sorry

I have a big problem , i need finish my applicatión in VB6.0 for a test in my High Schooll and i can`t  find the solution, My app open a FFmpeg.EXE file which open a cmd window Prompt and start a trascoding process, i  need link the last line generated into the Prompt of the CMD window (Or top Bottom) , in this line exists Values what change , in this trascoding process the result are bit Rates , which fluctuates acording to others var. 
The idea it´s what into the form of my app i can read this line in real time to bulid a progress bar (File Size/Bitrate average)=time to process.

Can you help me. Thanks for the answer....

Comment: Do you have any source code you can share?  That would really help us to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Put a reference to *Windows Scripting Host Object Model* and try this snippet

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim oExec       As WshExec
    Dim sRow        As String

    With New WshShell
        Set oExec = .Exec("tasklist.exe")
    End With
    Do While oExec.Status = WshRunning
        sRow = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
        If InStr(1, sRow, "vb6.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            MsgBox sRow, vbExclamation
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Basicly try executing FFmpeg.EXE and ReadLine until you find some key text.

Answer (score 0):

Send the output to a textfile then read this textfile.
Should look something like this:

```
ping >e:\test.txt
```

Where ping is the FFmpge.EXE and e:\test.txt the output textfile

Answer (score 0):

rdkleine

I read your answer and this is great work very good , only that it shows in the log a death value "text", and i need the value of fluctuates bitrates of conversion , which changes in real time in the prompt of the cmd window. i'm trying now with the source code of wqw , i'm working in there.

Thak's for your answer..